# Calculating MLE under restriction on coefficients

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, maximum-likelihood, consistency

Consider the following simple linear regression model:

$y_i = a + b \cdot x_i + \epsilon_i \space\space\space\space\space\space\space where \space i= 1, 2, 3, \cdots , n$

here $\epsilon_i \space's$ are i.i.d. normal random variables with mean 0 and variance 1.

(a) Find $\hat{a} \space and \space \hat{b}$, the maximum likelihood estimators of a and b with the restriction that $0 \le a \le 1$ and $0 \le b \le 1$

(b) Are $\hat{a} \space and \space \hat{b}$ always consistent?

I can calculate MLE without the restriction $0 \le a \le 1$ and $0 \le b \le 1$ but how to calculate it with this restriction on a and b. Also, the answer to the second part is that it is consistent only when there is a normal distribution, right?

Comment: for consistency, one only needs the orthogonality of error term and $x_{i}$ so $E(x_i \epsilon_{i}) = 0$. For the restrictions, there are many ways of restricting $a$ and $b$ to intervals. One way is to define a new variable say $a^{\prime} = \frac{a}{a+1}$ say and use that as the variable in the optimizaton or in your derivation of the MLE.

Comment: wouldn't defining a new variable change the question?